# Insertar texto de la URL en una sección de la página

Tags: wordpress

Hace tiempo miré un sitio web que hacía algo como lo que busco, sería algo así:
misitioweb.com/hola?n=Nombre%20Persona&7%20personas lo que busque es que es un, digamos, div se "imprima" y se muestre algo como: Nombre Persona, 7 Personas.

¿Es posible? Si sí ¿cómo podría resolverlo? Estoy usando WordPress, si sirve de algo. Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

**Edit:**
Cómo les comenté estoy usando WordPress, en un sitio hecho con Elementor. Bueno este fue el código que me ayudo a hacer lo que quería:

```
<?php echo $_GET["n"]; ?>
<br>
<?php echo $_GET["p"] . ' persona(s) -'; ?>
```

esto lo que hace es que cuando alguien entra a una url así: misitioweb.com/hola?n=John%20Doe&p=-%205 se muestran estos datos en el sitio.

No sé porqué no me deja poner números en el campo "p" tuve que poner esto en la url **p=-%205** porqué si solo pongo **p=5** no me muestra nada.

Comment: solo crea un formulario normal y envíalo por get, luego con php verifica si existen los datos y muéstralos, es algo básico de php o programación en General.

Comment: Mm en realidad no sé php, soy bastante nuevo en esto ¿tienes algún ejemplo?

Comment: Ya lo resolví, solo que no me deja mostrar números  https://misitioweb.com/hola?n=JOHN%20DOE&p=1 solo me imprime el nombre y el siguiente valor lo borra.

Comment: Bien, ahora que ya haz investigado por tu cuenta actualiza tu pregunta y agrega el código que haz probado, ya con ello podemos ayudarte en base a tu código, no olvides que siempre puedes leer [ask] y hacer el [tour]

Comment: Listo ya actualicé mi pregunta.

Comment: segun tu respuesta en el EDIT que hiciste:
Edit: Cómo les comenté estoy usando WordPress, en un sitio hecho con Elementor. Bueno este fue el código que me ayudo a hacer lo que quería: `<?php echo $_GET["n"]; ?>
<br>
<?php echo $_GET["p"] . ' persona(s) -'; ?>`
esto lo que hace es que cuando alguien entra a una url así: misitioweb.com/hola?n=John%20Doe&p=-%205 se muestran estos datos en el sitio. No sé porqué no me deja poner números en el campo "p" tuve que poner esto en la url p=-%205 porqué si solo pongo p=5 no me muestra nada.

Comment: como lograste hacerlo? yo tengo el mismo problema, estoy haciendo una invitacion con elementor y wordpress como logro llevar esos parametros a mi pagina para que se personalice la invitacion?? gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer lo que pides primero debes de crear un formulario, por ejemplo.

```
<form method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="n">
    <input type="number" name="p">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

Este formulario acepta un titulo que contiene el nombre del usuario y un numero, para ello se agrega un input text y un number respectivamente.

Luego se envía mediante el método Get a la url actual.

Para obtener esos datos podrias primero verificar si existe get

```
if ( isset($_GET) ) {
    // Tu Codigo
  }
```

Para obtener los datos primero obtienes Get mas el name del input, por ejemplo, para obtener el nombre seria algo como `$_GET['n']` Sin embargo al ser mediante el método Get lo recomendable seria limpiar la entrada para evitar que los usuarios agreguen código Javascript o SQL como método de seguridad.

Por ejemplo:

```
if ( isset($_GET) ) {

    $nombre = sanitize_text_field($_GET['n']);
    $personas = absint($_GET['p']);

    echo 'Hola ' . $nombre;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $personas . ' Persona(s)';

  }
```

la función sanitize_text_field() limpia el campo de texto eliminando código JS, HTML o SQL

la función absint convierte cualquier valor a un numero entero, esto también evita agregar código HTML, SQL o JS

Estas son funciones propias de WordPress por lo que si lo quieres probar en php puro tendrás que usar otras funciones.

Ahora bien, aunque esto no esta mal para formularios simples, si piensas obtener información importante como contraseñas lo mejor es usar POST, enviar la info por ajax y procesarla, el método Get solo es recomendable para información poco relevante.